# Нужна ли запятая после «но»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, деепричастный-оборот

***Но** добравшись до поясницы, эти самые импульсы замедлялись.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только союзы ‟и” и ‟а” могут в определённых ситуациях не отделяться от деепричастного оборота. Союз ‟но” всегда отделяется. Отделение ‟но” от деепричастного оборота требуется, так как ‟но” относится к ‟эти самые импульсы замедлялись”, а не к деепричастному обороту ‟добравшись до поясницы”.

Answer (score 3):

Правило Розенталя таково:
**Деепричастный оборот, стоящий после союза сочинительного или подчинительного либо союзного слова, отделяется от него запятой** (такой оборот можно «оторвать» от союза и переставить в другое место предложения):
*Наш отец Чимша-Гималайский был из кантонистов, но, выслужив офицерский чин, оставил нам потомственное дворянство и именьишко.

Жизнь устроена так дьявольски, что, не умея ненавидеть, невозможно искренне любить.

Становилось слышно, как, отсчитывая секунды с точностью метронома, капает из крана вода.*
**То же после присоединительного союза, которым начинается предложение** (союз стоит после точки):
*Но, рассмотрев всесторонне своё положение в роли мужа Вареньки, он засмеялся.

И, подойдя ко мне, сказал…*

Исключение составляют те случаи, когда деепричастный оборот (или одиночное деепричастие) стоит после противительного союза а (деепричастную конструкцию невозможно изъять из предложения или переставить в другое место без разрушения структуры предложения):
*Он начал приносить книги и старался читать их незаметно, а прочитав, куда-то прятал.

Необходимо принять срочное решение, а приняв его, неукоснительно проводить в жизнь.*

Однако при противопоставлении однородных членов предложения, связанных союзом "а", запятая после него ставится:
*Не стойте на месте, а, преодолевая одну трудность за другой, всегда стремитесь вперёд.

Элемент старого качества не исчезает, а, трансформируясь в других условиях, продолжает существовать как элемент нового качественного состояния.

Он не приводил никаких подробностей, а, говоря о своей теории в целом, излагал только её сущность.*
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113

Comment: Мне Ваш ответ нравится больше. Можно добавить примеры. **Но, добравшись до русла,** путешественники остановились в изумлении... [В. А. Обручев. Плутония (1924)] **Но, добравшись до своей цели,** туристки были гораздо менее поражены самим зданием, чем видом дамы, которая сидела поблизости... [Н. Н. Непомнящий. Загадки, гипотезы, открытия. Странное происшествие в Малом Трианоне // «Вокруг света», 1997]

Comment: Чегой-то, *oleedd*, от Вас нет никакой реакции. Вам не понравились примеры?

Comment: Примеры нормально. Что-то забыл прокомментировать. Хотел сказать, что это правило и правило о запятой на стыке союзов в середине предложения не соответствуют речевой практике, ведь пауза там почти всегда не делается, и из-за этого многие авторы пишут без запятой. Но тем не менее правильно остаётся так, как указано в правилах, на то они и существуют.